Flicker(blink) on zooming-in and zooming-out
I'm rendering a world map on a dashboard, and also displaying a pie chart(using leaflet mini-chart) on each continent which displays the percentage of males and females on that continent. Until I rendered only the map, everything was as expected, but as I rendered the pie charts, there is flicker(blink) coming when we zoom-in and zoom-out.
I used leaflet mini chart for displaying the pie charts on the map. Here is the link to the leaflet mini chart - https://github.com/JiniyaGupta/minichart_testing

Please include respective error messages and code snippets to improve the question and chances of getting community help.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
